# How to get the mic on the Creative X-Mod soundcard working correctly?

Tags: sound, microphone

Well, I have this problem for a while now. When my computer start the mic seem to work but it's like it's muted. I have to go to a terminal and type `alsamixer -c 1` and then I set up `PCM Capture Source` on `Line` and set up it back to `Mic` to get the mic actually working. Is there is a way to do this automatically or to solve the problem.

I use a special workaround on this card because of the bug [#429642](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/429642).
My workaround is having this at the end of my `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf` :

```
[Mapping xmod-stereo-out]
device-strings = surround51:%f
description = Analog Stereo Creative Xmod
channel-map = front-left,front-right
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-headphones analog-output-mono analog-output-lfe-on-mono
paths-input = analog-input analog-input-mic analog-input-linein analog-input-aux analog-input-video analog-input-tvtuner analog-input-fm analog-input-mic-line
priority = 10
```

Maybe the bug come from here, maybe I have to change something.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `-c 1` ?  Do you have more than one sound device?

Comment: Yes, there is an internal audio chip "Realtek ALC889A" and the Creative X-Mod is an external (USB) audio card.

Comment: please give us the output of lsusb in a terminal

Comment: Bus 002 Device 003: ID 041e:30d0 Creative Technology, Ltd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this automatically, amixer should do the job. It's the command-line-tool for Alsa-Mixer.

Comment: Yes I found it myself yesterday but I award you the bounty anyway since your response is correct. I create a script with this two commands : `amixer -c 1 sset "PCM Capture Source" "Line"` and `amixer -c 1 sset "PCM Capture Source" "Mic"` that I launch at startup and it work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two sound devices, maybe Pulse is trying to use the mic from the first card (-c 0) not the second (-c 1 -- your Creative).  Install and run `pavucontrol` and when you try to record, check which device it's trying to use. If the wrong one, change it.

Comment: I already use pavucontrol and I know how to configure the mic and it use the right one. The other one work correctly without problems but I want to use the mic on my Creative.